# Localstack on Windows 10 Home giving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, localstack

I am having issues getting Localstack to work on my **Windows 10 Home** System.  I have been running Docker Toolbox without any issues (for other things).

I have tried invoking Localstack in multiple ways (e.g. via docker-compose.yml or by directly downloading it from Docker Hub) but I am always getting the same result i.e. the Container says that Localstack is ready but when I try to connect to the Localstack services on my browser (e.g. http://localhost:4566) I get the following error:

> This site can’t be reached
>   localhost refused to connect error.
>   ...
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Reproduced below is one sequence of steps that I have taken to attempt to invoke Localstack (unsuccessfully I must add).

Command invoked: `docker run -it --name localstack  localstack/localstack:latest`

**Message trace....**

```
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
2020-05-04 20:02:27,144 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2020-05-04 20:02:27,154 INFO supervisord started with pid 13
2020-05-04 20:02:28,163 INFO spawned: 'dashboard' with pid 19
2020-05-04 20:02:28,173 INFO spawned: 'infra' with pid 20
2020-05-04 20:02:28,242 INFO success: dashboard entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
(. .venv/bin/activate; bin/localstack web)
(. .venv/bin/activate; exec bin/localstack start --host)
2020-05-04 20:02:29,246 INFO success: infra entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
LocalStack version: 0.11.0
LocalStack version: 0.11.0
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
!WARNING! - Looks like you have configured $LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=1 - please make sure to configure $HOST_TMP_FOLDER to point to your host's $TMPDIR
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
2020-05-04T20:02:42:INFO:localstack.utils.common: Unable to store key/cert files for custom SSL certificate: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/localstack/server.test.pem.key'
2020-05-04T20:02:42:INFO:localstack.services.install: Downloading and installing local KMS server. This may take some time.
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Starting edge router (https port 4566)...
Starting mock API Gateway service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4567 (deprecated)...
2020-05-04T20:02:48:INFO:localstack.multiserver: Starting multi API server process on port 51492
Starting mock CloudFormation service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4581 (deprecated)...
Starting mock CloudWatch service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4582 (deprecated)...
Starting mock DynamoDB service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4569 (deprecated)...
Starting mock DynamoDB Streams service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4570 (deprecated)...
Starting mock EC2 service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4597 (deprecated)...
Starting mock ES service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4578 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Firehose service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4573 (deprecated)...
Starting mock IAM service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4593 (deprecated)...
Starting mock STS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4592 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Kinesis service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4568 (deprecated)...
Starting mock KMS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4599 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Lambda service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4574 (deprecated)...
Starting mock CloudWatch Logs service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4586 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Redshift service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4577 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Route53 service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4580 (deprecated)...
Starting mock S3 service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4572 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Secrets Manager service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4584 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SES service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4579 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SNS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4575 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SQS service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4576 (deprecated)...
Starting mock SSM service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4583 (deprecated)...
Starting mock Cloudwatch Events service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4587 (deprecated)...
Starting mock StepFunctions service in http ports 4566 (recommended) and 4585 (deprecated)...
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready
Ready.
```

---

Since I kept getting the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` from the browser, I detached the terminal (Ctrl P+Q) and ran the following command in the container:
`netstat -a`

The output of the command is as follows:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2425           Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8092           Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:17500          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49673          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:65530          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:843          Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         Mywinmc:49669        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         Mywinmc:49670        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:17600        Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        Mywinmc:50106        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44430        Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49669        Mywinmc:5354         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49670        Mywinmc:5354         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50106        Mywinmc:27015        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50362        Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52800        Mywinmc:52801        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52801        Mywinmc:52800        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52805        Mywinmc:52806        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52806        Mywinmc:52805        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:139       Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.13:50247     20.185.212.106:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:51941     104.22.5.207:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:51949     server-13-249-79-178:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:51954     104.36.115.111:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:51963     server-13-249-75-45:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:52483     8.43.72.41:https       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:52486     104.17.119.107:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:52490     ip-185-184-8-30:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:53474     52.226.111.32:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:53665     ec2-34-194-118-104:https  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54028     104.26.8.27:https      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54104     bam-8:https            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54228     30:https               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54261     139:https              ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54265     151.101.49.253:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54266     a-0001:https           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54269     49:https               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54277     49:https               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54281     49:https               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54289     194:https              ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54355     162.125.35.135:https   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54378     162.125.8.13:https     CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54406     20.185.212.106:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54419     162.125.8.7:https      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54421     162.125.19.131:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54422     152.199.6.14:https     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54424     152.199.5.3:https      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54425     ec2-3-94-69-170:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54429     server-143-204-160-19:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54430     a23-193-18-78:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54440     a23-193-18-78:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54444     ec2-54-162-73-57:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54447     a23-67-241-31:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54470     server-13-249-79-42:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54474     104.16.68.69:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54478     a23-199-248-26:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54498     185.167.164.39:https   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54504     93.184.215.201:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54509     lb-140-82-114-3-iad:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54510     151.101.48.133:https   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54513     s3:https               TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54515     104.16.133.229:https   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54516     server-13-249-79-31:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54520     ec2-3-224-32-104:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54526     192.184.68.146:https   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54527     185.167.164.39:https   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54528     ec2-3-217-197-240:https  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54529     ec2-3-217-197-240:https  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54530     ec2-54-69-254-184:https  CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54533     54.239.17.112:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54537     232:https              ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:54538     r-17-48-62-5:https     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.13:60684     40.83.21.197:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:60695     52.242.211.89:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:60696     52.242.211.89:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:60780     ec2-3-224-94-60:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:61712     whatsapp-cdn-shv-01-dfw5:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:63209     9:https                ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:63395     Chromecast:8009        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:63705     on-in-f188:5228        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:63706     e1:https               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.13:63720     108-174-10-10:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.56.1:139       Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.99.1:139       Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8092              Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:17500             Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49664             Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49665             Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49666             Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49667             Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49668             Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49673             Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:49770            Mywinmc:0            LISTENING
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:2425           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5050           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:17500          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:49640          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:49774          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:54925          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55066          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:55739          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:57602          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:57603          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:57975          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:58140          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:58995          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:59072          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:59303          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:59698          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:60343          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:60813          *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49677        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49678        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:50019        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:58994        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59070        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:62643        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:64870        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:64871        *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.13:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.13:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.13:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.13:2177      *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.13:5353      *:*
  UDP    192.168.1.13:50018     *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:2177      *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:5353      *:*
  UDP    192.168.56.1:50016     *:*
  UDP    192.168.99.1:137       *:*
  UDP    192.168.99.1:138       *:*
  UDP    192.168.99.1:1900      *:*
  UDP    192.168.99.1:2177      *:*
  UDP    192.168.99.1:5353      *:*
  UDP    192.168.99.1:50017     *:*
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
  UDP    [::]:49775             *:*
  UDP    [::]:59303             *:*
  UDP    [::]:59699             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:5353             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:50015            *:*
  UDP    [fe80::6c83:b041:8dfb:82dd%6]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::6c83:b041:8dfb:82dd%6]:2177  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::6c83:b041:8dfb:82dd%6]:50014  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::9cd1:1694:a63e:e0c3%2]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::9cd1:1694:a63e:e0c3%2]:2177  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::9cd1:1694:a63e:e0c3%2]:50013  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::e8c8:ff57:e70f:27e1%19]:546  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::e8c8:ff57:e70f:27e1%19]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::e8c8:ff57:e70f:27e1%19]:2177  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::e8c8:ff57:e70f:27e1%19]:50012  *:*
```

---

It is clear that mock services are not running in the container, despite what the message trace of `docker run -it --name localstack  localstack/localstack:latest` suggests (as shown above).

---

Even the following command did not work:
`docker run -it --name localstack2  -e HOST_TMP_FOLDER="/tmp" localstack/localstack:latest`

Comment: I have the very same problem. Localstack’s log tells it’s listening on 4566, but netstats tells there’s no listener for that. It smells like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are your ports mapped to the host?

```
docker run -it --name localstack  localstack/localstack:latest -p 4567-4584:4567-4584
```

try adding the `-p` param to your docker command

Comment: The following command works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  `docker run -it -p 4566-4597:4566-4597 -p 8080:8080 --name localstack localstack/localstack` but unfortunately it does not work on Windows 10 Home Edition.