# Localstack on Windows vs Linux (Docker issue?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, localstack

This post is a follow-up to a [previous post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601415/localstack-aws-giving-err-connection-refused), where I documented the issues that I am having running Localstack on **Windows 10 Home**.  In a nutshell, I am able to run Localstack on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** without any issues but on **Windows 10 Home**, I keep getting *ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED* when I try to access the mock AWS services from my browser.

The command that I am invoking (successfully on Linux but unsuccessfully on Windows 10) is:

```
docker run -it -p 4566-4597:4566-4597 -p 8080:8080 --name localstack localstack/localstack
```

Could this be a Docker issue?  I wonder if there is any documentation on the "funny behavior" (if any) of Docker Toolbox for Windows 10 Home that could explain why this disparity between Windows and Linux.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to connect to?

Comment: @David-Maze I am using URLs like `http://localhost:4566` and `http://localhost:4572`.  They work as expected on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but they give ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? @Sandeep as I'm having the same issues

Comment: @Travisty no, I have not been able to get it working on Windows. Please share details if, and when, you get this working.

Comment: @Sandeep my current situation is this:

Windows 10, running localstack (running s3 etc). Firefox can view bucket endpoint (Chrome can't). http://localhost:4572/

Powershell can curl s3 bucket endpoint (command line can't)

Ubuntu WSL (running within windows 10....can call all localstack functions)...but every windows terminal can't.

I'm trying to work out why Ubuntu WSL works even though it's calling services running on a docker container in Windows. Very confusing.....